# return false in if statement not recognized in IE - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

The following code checks to see if user entered their email address & password.

This works great in Firefox/Chrome, but I'm having issues in IE. In IE, when you don't enter your user name and password, it turns the boxes red (as expected), and also doesn't change the text to 'Loading...', so it goes to the return false in the last else statement, but IE doesn't recognize it for some reason—is there a work around I should know about?

```
$('#gettheiremail').submit( function() { 
    var passwordinfo = $('#passwordtextbox').val();
    if ($('#signuptextbox').attr('value') == '' || $('#signuptextbox').attr('value') == 'Your Email Address' ) {
        $('#signuptextbox').css('color','red');
        $('#signuptextbox').css('border','3px solid #ff0000');
    }
    if ($('#passwordtextbox').attr('value') == '') {
        $('#fakepassword').css('color','red');
        $('#fakepassword').css('border','3px solid #ff0000');
        $('#passwordtextbox').css('border','3px solid #ff00000');
    }
    if((!($('#signuptextbox').attr('value') == '' || $('#signuptextbox').attr('value') == 'Your Email Address' )) && $('#passwordtextbox').attr('value') != '' )
    {
        $('#sendform').val('Loading...');       
    }
    else
    {
        return false;       
    }
});
```

**Here's the working code after fixes**

```
$('#gettheiremail').submit( function(e) { 
    var signuptextbox = $('#signuptextbox').attr('value');
    if (signuptextbox == 'Your Email Address' ) {
        $('#signuptextbox').css('color','red');
        $('#signuptextbox').css('border','3px solid #ff0000');
        e.preventDefault();     
    }
    var passwordtextbox = $('#passwordtextbox').attr('value');
      if (passwordtextbox == '' || passwordtextbox == 'Enter Your Email Password') {
        $('#fakepassword').css('color','red');
        $('#fakepassword').css('border','3px solid #ff0000');
        $('#passwordtextbox').css('border','3px solid #ff00000');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if(!((passwordtextbox == '' || passwordtextbox == 'Enter Your Email Password') && (signuptextbox == 'Your Email Address')))
    {
            $('#sendform').val('Loading...');           

    }

});
```

Comment: What do you mean "not recognized"?

Comment: it doesn't do the equivalent of return false.  Specifically, it doesn't stop the form from submitting

Comment: Can you add an `alert("test");` just above the `return false;` to verify that it is indeed reaching that block as expected?

Comment: @Andrew: `alert` debugging? **[In 2011?](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html)** ;-)

Comment: Seems to [work OK in IE 9](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/N3P4h/) for me.

Comment: Not the problem, but don't set css rules directly with javascript like this.  Instead use jQuery's `addClass()` and `removeClass()` methods, in order to change between these 2 visual states.  It will be faster, and far more maintainable.

Comment: It's faster than explaining using a debugger in a comment `:P`. Believe me, I'm all for `console.log` and the browser's JS console, hell of a lot less annoying.

Comment: @Marcel, don't expect that to be the least bit of an indication as to something working in an earlier version of IE.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm not talking about `console.log`, that's still `alert` debugging (or, showing my age, `printf` debugging) in my book. :-) I'm talk about a debugger. Single-stepping through code, examining variables with inspectors, etc., etc. In 2011 there's really [no excuse](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html) not to use a proper debugger. There's a free one, usually quite a *good* free one, frequently built-in, for basically every desktop browser.

Comment: @T.J. "JS console" was an all-enveloping term, which probably wasn't clear. And I can't even think of any non-free Javascript debuggers because all the free ones are excellent.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
$('#gettheiremail').submit(function(e) { 
   /* Other code */
   e.preventDefault();
   /* Other code */
});
```

Comment: Note that even though this didn't help, this is the preferred method of doing what you're trying to do, as `return false;` behaves a bit differently and not always as one would expect (though in most cases it doesn't matter, it's still good practice).

Comment: `window.event.returnValue = false` for IE, not `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @Matt: He's using jQuery, which provides `event.preventDefault()` on all supported browsers, including IE: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Answer (score 1):

If neither of the two things at the end of your code are happening, then the odds are that you're never reaching the end of that code — e.g., that an exception is being thrown in the middle. You'll want to walk through with a debugger (you can use the built-in stuff in IE8+, or VS.Net [there's a free edition] for earlier versions).

---

**Off-topic**: You're reiterating a lot of lookups:

```
if ($('#signuptextbox').attr('value') == '' || $('#signuptextbox').attr('value') == ' ...
```

**Every time** you write `$('#xyz')` it triggers several function calls, at least one memory allocation, and causes a DOM lookup (which is not necessarily all that fast, even when looking up by `id`). Similarly, constantly calling `attr` again for the same attribute is more unnecessary overhead (though not nearly so much). Instead:

```
var signuptextbox = $('#signuptextbox'),
    signupvalue   = signupvalue = signuptextbox.attr('value');
if (signupvalue == '' || signupvalue == '...
```

(Or don't keep the `signuptextbox` if you just need its value.)

Comment: You're right - thanks.  Commenting out the other code in that function except for e.preventDefault() and it's working - off to debug!